# Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted on aws instance triggered by jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, amazon-ec2, android-gradle-plugin

I'm setting up a new Jenkins build for an android app to run tests. I have downloaded android tools on the AWS instance. Then run the following commands to install additional packages to install platforms and build tools.

`./android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-28.0.3,android-28,extra-android-m2repository./android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-28.0.3,android-28,extra-android-m2repository`

This downloaded the correct platform and build-tools.

To build the app I run `gradlew :app:assembleDebug`
and i'm met with the following error

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
>        build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3

I have tried updating the licenses via the sdkmanager with the following commands -

yes | `./sdkmanager --licenses && ./sdkmanager --update`

and

`./sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"`

I am then met with All SDK package licenses accepted.However, when I attempt to build again I get

> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
>        build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3

I have also changed the permissions on the folder structure using chmod 777

Answer (score 1):

When I build and apk I don't need to accept the licenses every time, just one time before my Jenkins configuration.

I did it with this steps:

- Go to your $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
- Execute:

```
    ./sdkmanager --licenses
```

Without "yes |"

This will ask you to accept or reject licenses. You must accept all licenses.

Next time when you run build commands, licenses will not a problem.

Check this link to get a full guide of Android automated builds:

https://jrichardsz.github.io/android/how-configure-android-tools-for-automated-builds

Comment: I will try this when I return home from work. Thanks and will update shortly.